# ¿Como realizar una consulta en mysql usando count?

Tags: mysql, sql

No logro realizar la consulta que me devuelva la cantidad de municipios de los reportes, ejemplo:

```
|municipio | cantidad |
|----------|----------|
|ACAJETE   |   4      |
|PANTEPEC  |   5      |
|PUEBLA    |   1      |
```

En la tabla reporte:
tabla reportes

```
idReporte
descripcion
localidad_id   fk
```

Tabla localidades:

```
idLocalidad
nombreLocalidad
municipio_id   fk
```

Tabla municipios

```
idMunicipio
nombreMunicipio
region_id    fk
```

Tabla regiones:

```
idRegion
nombreRegion
```

Para realizar la consulta que necesito tengo relacionado 4 tablas las cuales fueron mencionadas anteriormente, pero no logro obtener la cantidad de municipios que se realizaron en los reporte. Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT m.nombre, count(m.idMunicipio) as cantidad_municipios
FROM reportes  
left join  localidades ON reportes.localidad_id = localidades.idLocalidad 
left join municipios m on m.idMunicipio = localidades.Municipio_id
left join regiones on regiones.idRegion = m.region_id WHERE regiones.idRegion=4;
```

Me devuelve este resultado pero no es lo que quiero y no entiendo como realizar la consulta

```
nombre           cantidad_municipios
ACAJETE              10
```

El resultado que deseo obtener para el reporte es el siguiente:

```
|municipios | cantidad_municipios |
|-----------|---------------------|
|ACAJETE    |   4                 |
|PANTEPEC   |   5                 |
|PUEBLA     |   1                 |
```

Con estos resultados posteriormente realizare una grafica de barras que muestre un ejemplo como: En acajete se obtuvieron 4 reportes, pantatepec: 5 reportes y asi sucesivamente

Comment: necesitas que te aparezca el nombre y la cantidad de municipios de cada uno?

Comment: coloca una muestra de como te gustaría obtener el resultado, así como una muestra de los datos que contiene cada tabla involucrada de preferencia

Comment: si, las veces que se repitieron en los reportes, para asi realizar una grafica de estadisticas que diga reporte de este año : en acajete hubo 4 reportes, puebla 10 y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Se podría usar tu consulta como subconsulta para un `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (/* la subconsulta */);`. Funcionaría, aunque podría haber formas más óptimas de hacerlo. Las subconsultas tienen inconvenientes.

Comment: y si pruebas añadiendo al final de tu consulta un `GROUP BY (m.nombre)` ? digo finalmente estas haciendo uso de una función de agregación `COUNT()` ahora solo falta agrupar por alguna razón esos valores y como requieres mostrar el listado de municipios y sus reportes a mi se me ocurre que al final de tu consulta pongas eso

Comment: Excelente amigo. Muchísimas gracias solo falto añadir GROUP BY (m.nombre). a mi consulta y funcionaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final de tu consulta deberías agregar lo siguiente:

```
GROUP BY (m.nombre)
```

La razón estas ocuando una función de agregación; la de `COUNT()` necesitas agrupar los resultados del conteo que haga dicha función; ahora por otro lado la columna que usarás es la de: `m.nombre` por que son los nombres de los municipios los cuales mostrarás agrupados.

Detalle importante

Noto que estás haciendo uso de un `WHERE` al final de tu consulta; deberías considerar que, el orden es del modo siguiente

```
WHERE columnName .......
GROUP BY(m.nombre);
```

Es decir el `GROUP BY()` va después del `WHERE`

Comment: Excelente amigo, solo era añadir el group. Muchas gracias